# Cannot change color of special characters on Android browser

Tags: android, html

I tested a web page on a Samsung S6 with Android 5 on it.  Here's the test code.

```
<html>
 <div style="color:green">&#10004;</div>
</html>
```

When I view this page on desktop browsers, the check mark is green.  When I view it on the Android device, it is always red.  Any ideas how I can make sure it is green on all devices?

thanks

Comment: Your question is unrelated with android developing.

Comment: What happens if it's not a "special" character but just an "ordinary" one? Maybe it's something about numeric entities. Try this: `<span style="color:#006600;">&#65;</span>`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566433/ascii-check-mark-is-always-red-in-mobile for explanation (it renders as emoji) and workaround (use &#10003; and css)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<span style="color:#ff0000;">&#10004;</span>
```

Comment: Why `#ffaa00`? That's more like orange.

Comment: I used:
    "<span style="color:#006600;">&#10004;</span>"

The color still appears red on my android device.  If I replace the special character with text, it does appear green.  It almost seems like some special characters are reserved by the browser's use and must remain red.  I could change to a different character, but I guess I refuse to give up on this.  I don't know why it won't change color for me.

Answer (score 0):

Trying following CSS code, to let the original color transparent first:

color:transparent;text-shadow:0 0 green ;